# Angular project component style don't want to display

Tags: html, css, angular, navbar, mean-stack

i'm trying some css test on my project, but one of my component don't want to show his css.

This is my Angular structure : [image: Angular project structure]

my app.component.html

```
<div id="nav-bar">
  <div id="nav-bar-content">
  <div id="nav-bar-left">
  <div>Pangolin</div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav-bar-right">
  <div>Register</div>
  </div>
  </div></div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

my app.component.css

```
#nav-bar {
  border: solide 5px red;
 
}
```

my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'socialnetworkapp';
}
```

and this is what i have in my browser :

[image: navbar display]

and this is my app.module.ts

```
// built in
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
//component import
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './components/account/account.component';
import { PageOneComponent } from './components/page-one/page-one.component';
import { navbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './components/sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AccountComponent,
    PageOneComponent,
    navbarComponent,
    SignUpComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My `/src/app/components/page-one` module works perfectly. Is it some children, parents issue there  ? I'm new on Angular

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is incorrect, `solide` should be `solid`:

```css
#nav-bar {
  border: solid 5px red;
}
```

See [MDN border-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) for a full list of valid border styles.

Comment: my bad, yes your right, but event with `solid` , my css isn't display

Comment: In your browser's dev tools, if you inspect the nav bar element, what do you get?

Comment: i have no errors, i can see my navbar and my Ids, but i have no css style. For exemple for my  `<div id="navbar">` i only have `div { display:block }`